# How to wire two GE Enbrighten Z-Wave Switches for a Common Bath Fan?

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, smart-switch, z-wave

**Question**:
How do I wire two GE Enbrighten Z-Wave switches that control a single bath fan?

**Background**:

- There are two bathrooms
- Each bathroom has a switch to control a common bath fan
- The fan will be on when *either* switch is in the ON position (different than any 3-way switch that I have experience with
- I've wired up over two dozen of these switches in my home already (including 3 different 3-ways). I've got some experience with them, I've just never encountered switches like this where the load is hot despite the position of the other switch.

**Existing Wiring**:
The existing switches are wired like this:
[image]

**Typical 3-Way Wiring:**
Wiring for a typical 3 way for GE Enbrighten switches looks like this:
[image]

Thanks.  Let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: Travelers go from switch to switch....  so were are your load wires? How is your fan hooked up to the switches in your first picture?

Comment: @JACK they're red wire, so I assumed travelers.  They go into the box and bundle to a black (presumably load) wire.  How can I verify that?
With my Klien voltage detector, the red wires are not hot unless the switch they are connected to is flipped on.

Comment: So you have parallel hots going to the same load..... that's so not good.  Do you have a conduit installation or NM cable? You'll need to add more wire and jockey things round. Personally, this seems like a waste of smart switches.

Comment: @JACK its NM cable, no conduit.  I'm not sure if it's parallel hots going to the same load. How can I verify that? And if that is the case, why is it bad?
I'm sure its not common, but it makes sense for a bath fan shared by two bathrooms to be wired like this. You'd want the fan to be on when either switch is in the ON position, unlike like a normal 3-way.

Comment: Where is the fan in relation to the bathrooms?  Can you hear the fan running in both bathrooms.  Normally there would be separate fans for each bathroom.

Comment: @JACK the fan is in the mechanical room. You can hear it from the lower bathroom (same floor) but not the upper bathroom.

Comment: @AdamKonieska -- what are you trying to accomplish with Z-Wave control of a bath fan?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel despite my efforts, humans can't remember to turn the fan on. Its been letting moisture accumulate in the attic, which in the winter seeps into the attic and freezes, finally melting in the spring and leaking through the ceiling.  So, humidity/moisture sensor and turn the fan on when its needed. In addition to more attic insulation and checking repairing any moisture barriers.